# Graph Edge equality Java

Tags: java, graph, logic

I'm building a solution for a MST problem, and I've run into an issue: how do you logically represent equality of an undirected weighted graph, i.e. two edges are equal iff they arise from the same vertices and have the same weights? Is this correct? It seems to work, however, I  find it difficult to find cases where it would fail.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(final Object o) {
    if (this == o) {
        return true;
    }
    if (!(o instanceof Edge)) {
        return false;
    }
    Edge<?> other = (Edge<?>) o;
    return areTheSame(other);
}

boolean areTheSame(Edge<?> other) {

    // Two edges are "the same" iff
    // V1 -> V2, weight X
    // V2 -> V1, weight X

    boolean symmetric = this.from.equals(other.from);
    boolean leftSym = this.to.equals(other.from);
    boolean rightSym = this.from.equals(other.to);
    boolean leftOtherSym = other.to.equals(this.from);
    boolean rightOtherSym = other.from.equals(this.to);

    boolean sameW = this.weight.equals(other.weight);

    boolean symmWeightSame = symmetric && sameW;

    boolean asymm = ((leftSym && rightSym) || (leftOtherSym && rightOtherSym)) && sameW;

    return asymm || symmWeightSame;
}
```

Comment: Are you going to allow multiple edges between two nodes? Also what is the type of weight?

Comment: By definition I assume that an edge between two vertices is, in fact, two edges, with origin and destination vertices swapped. Essentially, when initialising the graph, I "double" the amount of edges in the graph where I add the corresponding "reverse" edge to the adjacency list.

Comment: Your code will fail (return true) when both edges start from the same vertex but lead to different ones. And unless there is something really weird going on in `Vertex.equals`, then always `leftSym == rightOtherSym` and `rightSym == leftOtherSym` so you basicly can skip half of the comparison.